# nullpointerexception using lv.setadapter() method

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-tabs

so I have read a lot of post here that involve this, but none of them have helped me , since usually what happends is that the listview is not created when the set adapter methos is called, but in my case I have both of them created on the same OnCreateView() which is why i do not know why i keep getting this

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.student_lists;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.resources.student_list.Student;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    EditText inputSearch;
//  static ListView lv;
//  static EditText inputSearch;
    //static MyListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Student> implements Filterable{

        private final Context context;
        public ArrayList<Student> displayValues;
        public ArrayList<Student> originalValues;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Student> values) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.displayValues = values;
            this.originalValues = (ArrayList<Student>) values.clone();
        }

        public int getCount(){
             return this.displayValues.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //----This method sets each row of the list individually----            
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);

            if(displayValues.size() > 0)
            {
                Student student = displayValues.get(position);

//                          //Fill Name
                            TextView name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
                            name.setText(student.getFirstName() +  student.getLastName());

            }           
            return itemView;

        }

        public Filter getFilter() {

            Filter contactFilter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                 FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();   
                 ArrayList<Student> filteredList = new ArrayList<Student>();

                 //Filter the list
                 if(constraint != null && originalValues !=null) {

                     if(!constraint.toString().isEmpty())
                     {  
                         String constraintLowerCase = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                            for(Student c: originalValues)
                            {                           
                                String cName = c.getFirstName().toLowerCase() ;
                                String cLName = c.getLastName().toLowerCase();
                                if(cName.startsWith(constraintLowerCase) || cLName.startsWith(constraintLowerCase)) 
                                {
                                    //Add the row to the list if filtered items
                                    filteredList.add(c);
                                }
                            }                                            

                     }

                   //Important steps to store the filtered list
                    filterResults.values = filteredList;
                    filterResults.count = filteredList.size();
                  }
                  return filterResults;
              }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
              @Override
              protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {                                                                                              
                  if (results.count > 0) 
                  {         
                    //Display the filtered list
                MyListAdapter.this.displayValues = (ArrayList<Student>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      if(inputSearch.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                      {                 
                        //Display the original list
                          MyListAdapter.this.displayValues = (ArrayList<Student>) MyListAdapter.this.originalValues.clone();
                      }
                      else
                      {                     
                        //Display an empty list
                          MyListAdapter.this.displayValues.clear();
                      }                 
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                  }
              }
             };

            return contactFilter;

        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);

            switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){
            case 0:

            case 1:

                Student andres = new Student();
                andres.setFirstName("Andres");
                andres.setLastName("Blanco");

                Student ondria = new Student();
                ondria.setFirstName("Ondria");
                ondria.setLastName("Arias");

                ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
                studentList.add(andres);
                studentList.add(ondria);

                MainActivity mainactivity = new MainActivity();
                ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                //inputSearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
                MyListAdapter adapter = mainactivity.new MyListAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_view, studentList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                return rootView;

            case 2:

            }

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my LogCat report:

```
04-14 02:09:53.667: D/dalvikvm(1348): Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-14 02:09:53.751: D/dalvikvm(1348): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 103K, 5% free 3073K/3232K, paused 8ms, total 9ms
04-14 02:09:53.795: D/AndroidRuntime(1348): Shutting down VM
04-14 02:09:53.795: W/dalvikvm(1348): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d01b20)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348): Process: com.example.student_lists, PID: 1348
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.example.student_lists.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:304)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-14 02:09:53.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1348):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 02:28:04.931: D/dalvikvm(1442): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 109K, 6% free 3067K/3232K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
04-14 02:28:05.019: D/AndroidRuntime(1442): Shutting down VM
04-14 02:28:05.019: W/dalvikvm(1442): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d01b20)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): Process: com.example.student_lists, PID: 1442
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.example.student_lists.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:304)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-14 02:28:05.019: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me find whats causing my nullpointer.

Comment: package names should not have underscores in them...

Comment: I'm not sure you can set your Adapter in this way: `mainactivity.new MyListAdapter`. Try to using `new mainactivity.MyListAdapter` instead. Or put your Adapter inside your Fragment and then call `new MyListAdapter`. It should avoid the NullPointerException.

Comment: I tried writing it like new mainactivity.MyListAdapter but it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the adapter of the listview incorrectly. It should declare a new `MyListAdapter` as the following:

```
// Declare a new adapter and define its parameters:
MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter()
```

Your adapter class passes the parameters context, resourceId and arraylist. 
The resourceId is the textview you wish to populate with the arraylist.

You should be defining an itemId, not a layout. Between the context and the ArrayList place the textview resourceId you wish to populate with the ArrayList data.

```
// Declare a new adapter and define its parameters:
MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.YOURTVID, studentList);

// Then set the list adapter:
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: the way i did my custom listadapter I use a custom list_view layout which is the one I am using here

Comment: fixed it! just added the edit text searchbar and it worked! thx!

Comment: Great! Please accept and up vote this answer if I helped you at all.